# Joining two table with different from to intervals to update a column

Tags: sql, join

This is Dinesh, I have two different sql tables, tblDHDensity and tblDHLithology having different Depth_From and Depth_To intervals. I want to update Lith_Code field in the tblDHDensity when the from -to interval in tblDHDensity is within the from - to intervals of tblDHLithology. Please advise how can I do this. I am attaching the table structure for your reference.

[image: Update column]

Comment: Please include all data directly in your question as formatted _text_ (4 or more leading spaces on each line).  Also, you don't need to include irrelevant columns in your data.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and edit your post accordingly to those guidelines. Also note that Stackoverflow is not a coding service. We're a community site that thrives on helping like-minded programmers who has encountered a specific issue in their development process. In short, we'd like for you to write your own code so that we can disect the problem, but not build it for you ground-up. You have to show some effort.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 0):

This changes depending on which SQL DBMS you're using, but this is the general idea:

```
UPDATE schema.tblDHDensity density
INNER JOIN schema.tblDHLithology lith ON density.Hole_ID = lith.HoleID
SET density.Lith_Code = [whatever value you want]
WHERE density.Depth_To BETWEEN lith.Depth_From AND lith.Depth_To
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel! But it is missing few records. Would you please suggest how can I change the where condition little bit to include all the records

Comment: If you want to limit/expand the result set, you can add more columns to the `WHERE` clause using `AND`, so expanding on the current code would look like: 
`WHERE (density.Depth_To BETWEEN lith.Depth_From AND lith.Depth_To) AND density.Depth_From...`